# How To Create Expanding And Collapsing Of Row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How To Create Expanding And Collapsing Of Row in UITableView ,

I followed this video ,"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYaI5ASpsOE"   after clicked on cell I got following error.

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to compare <NSIndexPath: 0x600000029560> {length = 2, path = 0 - 18446744073709551615} with object of different class: NSArray'`

Comment: This is one of the best link try this .... http://www.iostute.com/2015/04/expandable-and-collapsable-tableview.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use [This](https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell) library. Just add it into your project using POD.

```
pod 'ExpandableCell'
```

Import it into your viewController

```
import ExpandableCell
```

Make ExpandableTableView in Storyboard or in code

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: ExpandableTableView!
```

Inherit ExpandableDelegate

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ExpandableDelegate
```

Set delegate

```
tableView.expandableDelegate = self
```

Reference: https://github.com/younatics/ExpandableCell

Comment: question is asked in Obj c not swift

Comment: This library is on Objective c, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/expandable-tableview

Comment: Please post in the answer y in the comment ?

Comment: Please check if it is working for you, then i will add it as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below tableview delegate and datasource code i used crash is not reproducible  to me

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return  self.arrowtitle.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ExpandingCell *cell = (ExpandingCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"Expanding Cell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.lblrow.text = self.arrow[indexPath.row];
    cell.lblrowtitle.text = self.arrowtitle[indexPath.row];
    cell.lblfruit.text = self.arrFruit[indexPath.row];
    NSInteger cal = (indexPath.row) * 25;
    cell.lblcalcal.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long) cal];

    return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) ? 120  : 45 ;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        self.selectedIndex = -1;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        return;
    }
    if (self.selectedIndex == -1) {
        NSIndexPath *prev = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedIndex inSection:0];
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
        [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[prev] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

}
```